# Problems with running a python script over many files

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am on a Linux (Ubuntu 11.10) machine; bourne again shell.

I have to process a directory full of files with a python script. My colleague wrote the python script and I have successfully used it before on one file at a time. It takes two arguments: a path to the file to be processed enclosed in quotes and a secondary argument called `-min` which requires an integer. Also, the script writes to standard out.

From my experience of shell scripting and following others on this forum, I used the following method to iterate over the directory of files:

```
for f in path/to/data_directory/*; do
  path/to/pythonscript.py $f -min 1 > path/to/out_directory/$f;
done
```

I get the desired file names in the `out_directory`. The content of each is something only the python script can write. That is, the above for loop successfully passes the files to the script. However, the nature of the content of each file is completely wrong (as in the computation the script does was wrong). When I run the python script on one of the files in the `data_directory`, the output file has the correct content (the computation performed by the script is correct).

The thing that makes it more complex is that the same shell method (the `for` loop) works perfectly in the Mac OS X my colleague has.

Where is the issue? Am I missing something very fundamental about Linux shells? Maybe it's a syntax error?

Any help will be appreciated.

Update: I just ran the for loop again but instead of pointing it to the data_directory of files, I pointed it to a file within the data_directory. I had the same problem - the python script did not compute the correct result.

Comment: Upvote for what exactly?

Comment: What is the command you're running for single files? Please, give us an example.

Comment: `path/to/pythonscript.py 'path/to/data_directory/10000.original_indels.ss' -min 1 > path/to/out_directory/10000.original_indels.ss`

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see is that filenames may contain white-space - so you should quote filenames:

```
for f in path/to/data_directory/*; do
  path/to/pythonscript.py "$f" -min 1 > "path/to/out_directory/$f"
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I went back and checked the file names and they do not have white space. `10000.original_indels.ss` is an example of the data files to be processed. I hope there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @nnarula Did you actually try Maulwurfn's script though? Because he also includes the entire path. Your shell code seems to depend on what the current directory is... perhaps you're running from a folder which has at least some common filenames as those in your data directory, but with different data (which is why the computations are wrong).

Comment: @azhrei Yes I did, I'm getting the same results. I am sitting one directory above the `data_directory`, the `out_directory`and the directory containing the python script. Also, because of the volume of data file that I will eventually be processing, I made sure to have no data files or out files in the directory I am working from.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know if this helps but.

```
path/to/pythonscript.py $f -min > path/to/out_director/$f
```

Substitutes out to

```
path/to/pythongscript.py path/to/data_directory/myfile -min 1 > path/out_directory/path/to/data_directory/myfile
```

script should be

```
cd path/to/data_directory
for f in *; do
path/to/pythonscript.py $f -min 1 >  path/to/out_directory/$f
done
```

What version of bash are you running?

what do you get if you run this script?

```
cd path/to/data_directory
for f in *; do
echo $f > /tmp/$f
done
```

of course that should give you a bunch of files containing their own file names.

Comment: Yes, I ran into that error when I first tried the script. Bash said `path/to/out_directory/path/to/data_directory/myfile` doesn't exist. I worked around that by creating a directory named data_directory in the out_directory [As I explained in a comment above, I am sitting one directory above the data_directory, the out_directory and the directory containing the python script]. My bash version is GNU bash, version 4.2.10(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). 
And yes, the output of the last script is exactly what you said it would be.

Comment: You've verified straight command on one or a couple of the files that failed in the for loop. Not just the same file. It could be this a python issue.

Comment: Yes, I am using 5 files in the data_directory right now for testing and I have tested the python script individually, without using a `for` loop, on each of them. The python script worked successfully. I have also replaced the 5 files with another set. Same scenario.

Comment: Is it possible that the python script isn't finishing prior to the next loop of the for loop starts?

Comment: I didn't know that was even possible, but I am fairly new to all of this so I am open to that suggestion. I don't know how to test that case though. Also, why does it work on my colleague's Mac?

Comment: Well just run the script in one console and in another console something like this 'while ; do ps -aux | grep <name of python script> done' if you see the script twice you know they are running at the same time.